# Установить windows с образа

Tags: windows, установка, образ

Доброго времени суток.
У меня есть новые компьютеры от 4 разных производителей. Всего примерно десять. Мне нужно установить на всех `windows 10`, и стандартный набор программ, как `office, adobe, chrome` и т.д. 
Я читал в сети, хотя и не понял как это делается, что можно установить все программы на одном компе, потом из него сделать загрузочный образ, потом этот установочный образ загрузить на другие компы. Вопросы вот какие:

1. Можно ли это сделать в принципе? (Компы у меня немного разные, хотя и новые).
2. Удастся ли (на ваш взгляд) сэкономить время при установке, если действовать таким способом? Подразумевается, что если загружать windows, а потом устанавливать ПО уходит более 5 часов.
3. Поделитесь ссылочкой на инструкцию, как это можно грамотно сделать?

Comment: Все компы разумеется с оперативой от 4гб и больше. То есть, не нуждаются в 32 битной ОС.

Comment: Может, поможет комментарий. Программы на Windows я устанавливаю при помощи пакетного менеджера [**Chocolatey**](https://chocolatey.org/). После успешной установки Windows на новый компьютер или переустановки ОС можно установить Chocolatey → запустить команду `choco install googlechrome adobereader anotherprogram -y`, где `googlechrome`, `adobereader` и `anotherprogram` — названия программ, которые хотите установить. Программы устанавливаются — Вы в это время занимаетесь другими делами. // На установку Windows и ПО явно меньше 5 часов у меня ушло в прошлый раз. Спасибо.

Comment: Плюс — ПО устанавливается автоматически. На установку расходуется время компьютера, не Ваше. Вы же пока можете делать что-то полезное. Спасибо.

Comment: Вот что удалось мне найти. как мне кажется это то что вам нужно:
https://mediapure.ru/hdd/kak-perenesti-sistemu-i-dannye-na-novyj-drugoj-kompyuter/

Comment: Задача может показаться простой, но на самом деле там хренова гора подводных камней. Напиши мне в жаббер, я тебе pdf'ок накидаю нужных. Тема слишком обширна, чтобы впихнуть её в один ответ. Даже для 10 компов.

Answer (score 0):

Добрый день. Я бы рекомендовал использовать загрузочную флешку от Sergey Strelec на которой есть Acronis true image . 
1) Подготавливаем эталонную машину.
2) Используем команду sysprep 
3) Загружаемся с загрузочной флешки делаем образ системы через Acronis true image
4) Загружаемся с флешки на другом ПК и разворачиваем образ с помощью Acronis true image.
По опыту инсталляция 1 ПК 15-20 мин